# Does a direct object always follow the transitive verb?

Tags: transitive-verbs, direct-objects

I am confused as to whether direct objects always follow the transitive verb. When I searched for an explanation online, it always says that direct objects always come after the transitive verb. I can't find an example where the direct object precedes the verb.

> In a sentence, the direct object is the noun or noun phrase that’s receiving the action of the verb. The basic construction works like this: Subject + Verb + Who or What.

https://examples.yourdictionary.com/direct-object-examples.html

> I ate the hotdog that she had given me.

In the first sentence, can you consider the verb "had given" a transitive verb despite its placement?

> "Goodbye!" she said.

I read one discussion that the direct object can precede a verb in a relative clause as long as it comes after the verb in the main clause. So, how can we explain the second sentence?  Is the verb "said" in the second sentence intransitive?

Comment: As stated, this doesn't make sense to me. Could you please add the details about this absolute answer, how it ready exactly, where it came from?

Comment: In your first example, the relativised element is object of "gave" in the relative clause, so we have "I ate the hotdog [that she had given me ___ ]", where gap '___' is co-referenced to "hotdog".

Comment: In your second example there is no object at all. Goodbye!" is an exclamation, and "she said" is a parenthetical, a kind of supplement.

Comment: English allows variation of word order in some circumstances, for certain purposes such as emphasis or in set formulas, so subject-verb-object is only a general rule with exceptions: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/word-order-and-focus_1

Comment: @StuartF Yes, but where is the 'variation in word order' in the OP's first example?

Comment: Stuart F is right. Here's an example: *"The book that she gave me was big."* Here, *'book'* is the object of the verb *'gave'*. The important thing for you to remember is **the object receives the action of the verb.** Just remember that for now.

Comment: @BillJ Just a follow up question, how do you classify "said" in the second sentence? Is it a transitive or intransitive verb?

Comment: @StuartF Thank you! Your comment is helpful.

Comment: @touchstone Thank you! I just got in an argument with a colleague who claims that if a verb is not followed by a direct object, then it is intransitive. I think I already got my answer for the first sentence.

Comment: There is no object in 'Goodbye!', she said", so "said" must be intransitive. In the example "The book that she gave me was big", "the book" is direct object of "gave" in the relative clause, just as "hotdog" is the object of "given" in the relative clause of your original example.

Comment: @BillJ, I've always thought that **"Goodbye!" she said."** is another construction of **"She said, "Goodbye!"** in which the verb _said_ is transitive and the direct object is _"Goodbye!"_ because the latter answers the question "_Said what?_"

Comment: @BillJ Does that follow that other verbs like _state_, _claim_, etc. can be intransitive in such construction? 

Example:

_"Men get paid more than women," she stated._
_"Johnny was the killer," the witness claimed._

I am confused now because those verbs are only transitive at least in the dictionary.

Comment: I'll retype my last comment which contained a typo: Incidentally, there are clauses (other than relative ones) where the verb in an embedded subordinate clause has a missing object that can be recovered from an antecedent expression in the main clause. For example, in "The problem took her only a few minutes [to solve __]", "the problem" is subject of the main clause and the understood object of "solve"; thus the bracketed infinitival clause is transitive.

Comment: @BillJ I think that is already settled. I hope you can address my other concern in the comment before yours.

Comment: Some older, mainly out-of-date, grammars claimed that the direct reported speech is object of the reporting frame, but modern scholarly grammar does not analyse it like that.